# Provisional package for Hololens 2 with Azure AD account creation

Tags: azure, hololens

Has anybody tried to do a provisioning package for hololens2 that includes AD account creation? I wish I had some automated provisioning package to recover a device with a default Azure AD account, the wifi known networks, dev settings and so on.

As of now it's always failing if I enable Azure AD account creation, in simple or advanced mode. I'm gettinng the AD token from the configuration designer, all checks are green, but when applied during OOBE I've an error with a code, and the creation fails.
I either fallback to account creation or end with a local user.

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share the error code you are experiencing?

This error (in specifying an AD account for pre-provision package) may be due to changes in the Windows Autopilot sign-in and deployment experience.

Administrators previously could assign a user (AD account) to the device using AutoPilot, but Microsoft took that feature away due to security. For example: If a device is sold to different party (but still pre-provisioned for the old owner), we do not want the device to report the old owner's username.   I believe we cannot pre-provision HoloLens2 with a specific user for the OOBE experience anymore.

These Changes are documented here:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/intune-customer-success/updates-to-the-windows-autopilot-sign-in-and-deployment/ba-p/2848452

Presently, a HoloLens 2 user account requires 2FA setup and I believe the 2FA setup is not available for OOBE deployment.

However, after you are finished configuring the HoloLens2 past the OOBE deployment, you do have the possibility of using autologonuser CSP so that the user automatically logs in (if applicable):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-mixedreality#mixedreality-autologonuser

Comment: Thank you for this insight, that may explain a lot